# Admin password is not working OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

Actually it works fine to login, and also when I execute something with `sudo`. But when I try to change preferences and window with login/password pops up, it says that password is incorrect.

So I actually cannot install anything.

Comment: I found out, that's because User name was in human form (I mean native language), if you write you unix login it works fine.

Comment: Well problem is still there, cause in some cases login/password prompt does not allow to change language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is – input language is not eng, even showing it is. Try delete any other input languages – worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured out the issue first you have to make another Admin account I did this by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7awY1KI2s8

DON'T USE THE SAME PASSWORD THAT YOU USED ON YOUR OTHER ACCOUNT I HAD PROBLEMS BECAUSE I DID THAT

If you are experiencing the same issues as me where the password didn't work
follow these steps to change the password

1. Restart the Mac
2. During when it's booting up go into recovery mode.
3. Once in recovery mode open up Terminal.
4. Enter this and then press enter: **resetpassword**
5. Reset password for the admin account that was made.
6. log into your new admin account and then make your other account an admin user.
7. Restart computer and then login to your account.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW - I had a similar issue with DP3 following a restart (I could not login with any account). After shutting down and booting again, I was able to login again.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Log in with iCloud solved it.